# Issue: No package 'libcrypto' found

Tags: c++, cmake, openssl, libcrypto

I saw this issue "No package 'libcrypto' found". The same error I fixed multiple months ago was to follow this solution: https://github.com/scipr-lab/libsnark/issues/99 
I tried this solution today however it doesn't work anymore. (I also tried"brew install openssl, brew info openssl") No luck. 
Have you seen this before? Would you help take a look?

```
-- Checking for module 'libcrypto'
--   No package 'libcrypto' found
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.15.4/share/cmake/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:458 (message):
  A required package was not found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.15.4/share/cmake/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:637 (_pkg_check_modules_internal)
  PlaylistParser/src/CMakeLists.txt:2 (pkg_check_modules)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Comment: Do you have the Crypto library installed?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`brew info openssl` says the following: (for me, might be different for you if your version is different)

```
openssl@1.1 is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
because openssl/libressl is provided by macOS so don't link an incompatible version.

If you need to have openssl@1.1 first in your PATH run:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc

For compilers to find openssl@1.1 you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include"

For pkg-config to find openssl@1.1 you may need to set:
  export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/pkgconfig"
```

Since your CMake script seems to use pkg-config, you only need to execute the last statement before you run `cmake`.

Comment: Straightforward and solid answer. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: this is by far the best answer, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

When I run `./install_prereq install-unpackaged` command, I'd got the following error.

> configure: error: Package requirements (libcrypto >= 1.0.1) were not
> met:
>
> No package 'libcrypto' found
>
> Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
> installed software in a non-standard prefix.
>
> Alternatively, you may set the environment variables crypto_CFLAGS and
> crypto_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config. See the pkg-config
> man page for more details.

Then I run the following command and the problem was solved;

```
yum install openssl-devel
```